# Show error when create a model.tt?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my mvc project when i create model.tt and model.context.tt it display a error message like
[image]

How to solve this problem? Any idea?

Comment: Your question needs more detailed informations..

Comment: i want add model.edmx model.tt and model.context.tt.I add this files in Model->Add->ado.net entity model.After create model.context.tt i show that error

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the tt file you should see a path that points to your edmx file.  That could be the thing that is wrong.  The tt file needs to know where your model resides in order to generate entity classes for it.  The path should be towards the top of your file.